# SSIS Build Error: Could not copy file to the deployment utility output directory

Tags: deployment, build, ssis, bids, sql-server-data-tools

### Problem

When attempting to build an SSIS package deployment utility by right-clicking on the solution and choosing "build", the build fails with an error message similar to the following:

> Error 204 System.ApplicationException: Could not copy file
>   "MyPath\MyFile.dtsConfig" to the deployment utility output directory
>   "MyPath\bin\Deployment".
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: The file 'MyPath\MyFile.dtsConfig' already exists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Cause

This is caused when SSIS is attempting to deploy multiple copies of the `.dtsconfig` file to the output directory.  By default, SSIS will copy both all dependent files (including `.dtsconfig` files) and any files added to the solution under the `Miscellaneous` folder.

If you have added the file to your solution, but failed to repoint the Package Configuration to the new location, both copies will be deployed, and the build will fail.

This scenario can occur when you:

1. Create a package using a Package Configuration with a `.dtsconfig` file
2. Copy the package to a new directory without editing the Package Configuration
3. Add the configuration file to the project by right-clicking the solution, choosing Add --> New Item, and navigating to the file
4. Build the package.

### Solution

To fix this, repoint your Package Configuration to the file underneath your solution directory.  This can be done through the editor, or can be done by viewing the XML code of your package and manually editing the path of the file, such as with the following:

```
  <DTS:Configurations>
    <DTS:Configuration
      DTS:ConfigurationString="MyPath\MySolution\MyFile.dtsConfig"
      DTS:ConfigurationType="1"
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{93222D3D-7AFF-1F2D-9UB8-B5E7X256BBE5}"
      DTS:ObjectName="MyFile" />
  </DTS:Configurations>
```

Further reading can be found [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic490098-147-1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by casing differences in the configuration file path.  In some instances SSIS will treat c:\MyPath\MyFile.dtsConfig differently than c:\mypath\MyFile.dtsConfig.

I tested this with two different computers connected to the same TFS server.  One pc had TFS mapped to C:\Packages.  The other pc had TFS mapped to C:\packages.  Creating a package and running on the first pc would create the deployment without any problems.  Trying to create the deployment package on the second pc would result in the could not copy exception.

I manually edited the .dtsx file on the second pc.  Changing the casing of the configuration file path under DTS:ConfigurationString= in the .dtsx file allowed the package to work correctly.

To get the package to work on both computers I updated the local path for TFS to have the same casing.